# creating a procedure phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm having a bit of trouble with creating a stored MySQL procedure in phpMyAdmin. If I write my procedure like I would in the console, it throws at syntax error. For example:

`DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE get_commission ()
 BEGIN
    SELECT e.E_ID, e.Lastname, e.Firstname, (SUM(Sold_For - Landed) * 0.12) as Total 
    FROM Cars_Sold s, Employees e
    WHERE e.E_ID = s.E_ID
    GROUP BY E_ID
    ORDER BY e.Lastname ASC;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;`

However, if I write just write the regular query (the one in the Begin/end block) it runs just fine. And I am writing this in the module in the routines tab. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can You please paste the syntax error?

Comment: See the link: http://i.imgur.com/0xCWasu.png

Comment: Maybe PhpMyAdmin adds the 'DELIMITER' logic itself, so You don't have to write it on Your own?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use delimiters in phpMyAdmin! Just copy everything between delimiters and paste in phpMyAdmin. Or - you can use SQL code box as well